# RibbonDropDown: Selection via Keyboard (OutlookAddin)

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook-AddIn where I have a RibbonDropDown filled with entries from a list. Since there will be a lot of entries, I want the user to be able to select/search an item by typing the entry. Up to now it's only possible to 'search' for the first letter by typing.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I tried ComboBox but somehow I failed as I want the user to ONLY be allowed to select available entries and I need to get the selected label afterwards as based on that other buttons/DropDowns will become available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office Ribbon controls do not implement this functionality. You can display a window with your own control after a user clicks your ribbon button.

Comment: Would you mind providing me with some code samples so I know where to go? It's my first Outlook AddIn!

Comment: What are you having problems with? Adding a button to a ribbon? Displaying a form? Finding a third-party control that will implement this functionality?

Comment: the form and the third party control so it looks like a "normal" dropdown list

Comment: Displaying a .Net form from a COM addin is not any different from displaying in a Windows app. As for a third party control, I can't help you with that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The Fluent UI provides a definiteve set of controls, none of which provides the required functinality. Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

As a workaround you may consider adding an Outlook form region where you can implement all what you need. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) for more information.

You may find [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php) helpful.